# System.Windows.Forms: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop

I have a vb.net application and converting into C# desktop application. In a screen i have an error-

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

code snipped is below:

```
CheckString = grvJobList[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Please help what is the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the control (or object) grvJobList is not constructed.  The default row count is -1 until the columns are added to the object and then the row count is set to zero until rows are added.  The error message is usually due to the row count being -1.

Comment: That line of code is out of context, you didn't even mention what event it relates to, when the exception is raised and what is the object that raises it. Post some code that can reproduce or helps to understand the problem and what's happening at that point.

Comment: @Jimi Here is the event of above code 'grvJobList_CellEndEdit' and error raised when i changed row using mouse.

Comment: How is the `CellEndEdit` event raised when you *change row using the mouse*? Do you have CheckBox columns there? Or some custom Column that hosts a different type of Control? DateTimePicker? ComboBox with secondary DataSource? What is the DataSource of your, I assume, DataGridView? Does it have/allow null values? Is this exception raised all the time, on any Cell change, or just with specific Columns? etc.

Comment: @Jimi...  Yes, Checkbox and dropdown are there in the grid. Data comes from sql sever using EF 6. This issue raises some randomly and some time regularly and it is not with any specific column.